# Is there Parallelism in my sentence

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure, parallelism

Does my sentence have parallelism?

"He criticizes public schools because they are compulsory, government-funded, and destroying students' humanity."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Not much

The only parallel construction here is in the three attributes the speaker assigns to schools: "compulsory, government-funded, and destroying students' humanity."  each of these links with "are", so the construction is parallel to that degree. But the attributes are expressed with different forms. The word "compulsory" is a simple adjective. the term "government-funded": is compound, and uses an -ed form that suggests a past action, although not in this case, but that reduces the parallelism. And "destroying students' humanity."uses a gerund form "destroying" which is at least awkward and arguably incorrect here.

> He criticizes public schools because they are compulsory, government-funded, and they destroy students' humanity.

would be better, in my view, but still not very parallel.

Comment: one more thing can you please tell me if this sentence sounds right?"Good health requires right eating and regular exercising."         It's clear that it's parallel but I can't tell if it's correct otherwise

Comment: @Qasim "right eating" is an unusual and awkward phrase in US English at least, but this should really be a separate question.

Comment: thanks i'll ask it as separate question then

Answer (score 1):

No, the last coordination

> compulsory, government-funded, and destroying students' humanity

connects two adjectives and a clause.

This would be parallel:

> compulsory, government-funded, and humanity-destroying.

That would be three adjectives, though the last adjective doesn't convey the same meaning as "destroying children's humanity".

It would be better to rephrase the original sentence:

> "He criticizes public schools because they are compulsory and government-funded, and are destroying students' humanity."

Answer (score 0):

> He criticizes public schools because they are compulsory, government-funded, and destroying students' humanity.

No, this sentence currently doesn't show parallelism. You can rephrase it as follows:

> He criticizes public schools because they are compulsory, government-funded, and humanity-destroying.

Now all three terms are adjectives which is how you would form parallelism in this case. Either all adjectives or all nouns or all prepositional phrases, etc.